# Why Lie derivative provides a representations of a Lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a book about general relativity. After introducing the Lie derivative and Lie bracket, the author claims that  the Lie derivative provides a representation of the Lie algebra of vector fields from  the relation
$$[L_V,L_V]=L_{[V,W]}$$
I can not understand this. What is the Lie algebra? and what is algebra relation? For me  Lie algebra is defined by some algebra relation
 for example
$$ [T^a,T^b]=if_{abc}T^c$$
 and the representaion of Lie algebra is something that satisfies the same algebra relation as Lie algebra components.

Comment: If you take the tangent space $T_e$ in the unit element $e$ of the Lie group , you'll find that vectors in this tangent space can be used to represent vector fields of the Lie group . Commutator of the vectors in Lie algebra $T_e$ corresponds to Lie derivative of one vector field with respect to another in the Lie group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lie algebra is simply a vector space with an alternating bilinear product (written as Lie brackets) that satisfies the Jacobi identity.  I'm not sure what you mean by "relations" here, maybe you are thinking in terms of generators and relations?  Since we did not define the Lie algebra that way, don't think of it in that terms.

For the quote, you are looking at the Lie algebra of *all* (globally defined, smooth) vector fields $\mathcal{X}(M)$ on some smooth manifold $M$, with the usual Lie bracket as the product, i.e,
$$
\mathcal{X}(M)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathcal{X}(M)\to\mathcal{X}(M)
$$
is the usual Lie bracket given locally as
$$
X^i\partial_i\otimes Y^j\partial_j\mapsto (X^j(\partial_jY^i)-Y^j(\partial_jX^i))\partial_i.
$$
Then the Lie derivative
$$
L\colon\mathcal{X}(M)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E)
$$
where $E$ is, say, a smooth vector bundle over $M$, provides a representation of $\mathcal{X}(M)$, i.e.,
$$
L\colon\mathcal{X}(M)\to\mathrm{End}(\Gamma(E))
$$
is a Lie algebra homomorphism.  In other words, $L$ is a linear map and $L$ of a Lie bracket of vector fields is the same as the corresponding Lie bracket of (continuous) endomorphisms of the space of sections of $E$.  That is what $[L_V,L_W]=L_{[V,W]}$ tells you.

Comment: Yes, generators and commutation relation is the way in which I think of Lie algebra. My major is physics. In physicist group theory book, it is always said that Lie algebra is determined by the structure constant.